# NSDate fixing timezones

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I know that NSDate doesn't have timezone information.

However, I'm trying to understand how to manipulate them properly.

At the moment I'm passing a date into an object. That date is the user selected date at time 00:00:00.

i.e. if the user hits October 21st then the NSDate passed in should be. 21/10/2013 00:00:00.

However, it isn't it's 20/10/2013 23:00:00. (One hour before).

Now, this is nothing about formatting them or displaying them. I'm just using the NSDates.

I'm creating the date using `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`.

**I guess my question is...**

How can I tell what date an `NSDate` is actually referring to in my local time zone?

I need to send a UNIX time stamp for 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 for a given date. However, at the moment when I set the hour, minute and second to 0, 0 and 0 then I'm not getting midnight in the current time zone I'm getting midnight in GMT.

This isn't what I want.

**Fixed?**

OK, I've fixed it... I think. At least, it's doing what I want it to do.

The trick is...

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateComponents setSecond:timeZone.secondsFromGMT];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been confused by this many times. When you `NSLog` an NSDate, you'll always get the output in GMT. So the 20/10/2013 23:00:00 (GMT) you're seeing **is** the same as your expected 21/10/2013 00:00:00 (BST). The UNIX timestamp for both of these dates would be the same because it doesn't take into account timezone - it's always UTC.

If you want to output in a user-readable format, an `NSDateFormatter` will format the date using your current timezone and locale.

Comment: Just an additional note: If you want `NSLog` to output the date in your current timezone, use `NSLog(@"%@", [date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);`

Comment: Oh, balls. Turns out this was a formatting problem :( I hadn't set the time zone on a NSDateFormatter. Still, this is all just ultra confusing. Still can't fully get my head around it lol.

Comment: The issue here is that NSDate really could more accurately be called NSMomentInTime. It's *just* a double containing an offset from a reference moment.

Comment: OK, nope, still messed up. I have to make changes to NSDateComponents based on the time zone to correct it. :(

Comment: Exactly @Catfish_Man if I get the components of an `NSMomentInTime` and set the hour component to 0 then it should be 0. Not 23. I still don't understand this :(

Comment: From the docs: "Important:  An NSDateComponents object is meaningless in itself; you need to know what calendar it is interpreted against, and you need to know whether the values are absolute values of the units, or quantities of the units."

Comment: So NSDateComponents needs to be manually adjusted based on the time zone which you have to manually get hold of. Which explains why my fix works.